# Dynamical System with Complex Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, dynamical-systems

We are learning about decoupling dynamical systems in linear algebra right now, and I am having some trouble with this problem. I don't understand what to do when we have a function $x(t+1)$, rather than the regular $x(t)$. Furthermore, reducing the matrix $A$ gives me complex eigenvalues. Would someone mind giving me direction (and/or a solution) for this problem? Thank you.

Find real-valued closed formulas for the trajectory $x(t+1)=Ax(t)$, where
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    6 & -8\\
    8 & 6\\
    \end{bmatrix}$  and  $x⃗ (0)=\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    1\\
    \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: It's a difference equation, not a differential equation. In other words, a discrete-time dynamical system. (It's understood from the context that $t$ takes integer values only.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $\theta=\arctan(4/3)$, we can write
$$\begin{pmatrix}6&-8\\8&6\end{pmatrix}=
10\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}.$$
So
$$\begin{pmatrix}6&-8\\8&6\end{pmatrix}^{n}=
10^{n}\begin{pmatrix}\cos n\theta&-\sin n\theta\\\sin n\theta&\cos n\theta\end{pmatrix}.$$
So
$$x(n)=\begin{pmatrix}6&-8\\8&6\end{pmatrix}^{n}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=
10^{n}\begin{pmatrix}-\sin n\theta\\\cos n\theta\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: How did you get the 10 ?

Comment: Well $\cos\theta=3/5$ and $\sin\theta=4/5$ so...